# Is the Type of Trigger is limited to just one, when I want to publish GAS project as Add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, add-on

I am developing GAS project, where users freely add Trigger to their own sheets.
Now, I want to publish it as Sheets-Add-on.

But I heard rumors that the **type** of trigger is limited to only one when the project is published as Add-on.

They said that Add-on (that has many **types** of Trigger) will fail to pass Google's examination.

I try to search this on  official Google documentation, but I cannnot find the source.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

For example,  Could not Sheets-Addon have onEdit-trigger and onChange-trigger together?

Comment: Yes, that is true. If you need further help on this please add a brief description of your search/researche efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I add a brief description. I need the answer to `For example, Sheets-Addon cannnot have onEdit-trigger and onChange-trigger together??`......

Answer (score 3):

No. That is not true. As written in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers#restrictions_2),

> Each add-on can only have **one trigger of each type, per user, per document**. For instance, in a given spreadsheet, **a given user can only have one edit trigger, although the user could also have a form-submit trigger** or a time-driven trigger in the same spreadsheet. A different user with access to the same spreadsheet could have their own separate set of triggers.

You can have a trigger of each type.  You can have a edit and a onChange type trigger together as they're of different **type**, but only 1 trigger of each type. You can't have two `edit` triggers. You don't need it any way. Whatever needs to be done on edit can be done in 1 trigger function.